# Tornado: file log is also write to stdout

Tags: python-2.7, logging, tornado

I'm using FileHandler to write tornado access logs into file, but the same log is output to stdout.

```
from tornado.options import define, options

options.logging = None
options.parse_command_line()

access_log = logging.getLogger('tornado.access')
access_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = logging.FileHandler(log_path)
access_log.addHandler(handler)

// stdout::
INFO:tornado.access:200 GET / (ip) 0.93ms
```

It does write into log file, but I don't know why it's also output to stdout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's logging framework is based on a hierarchy of loggers. Whatever is logged to `tornado.access` is also by default propagated to the root logger (which goes to stderr by default). If you don't want the access log to get duplicated, set the [`propagate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate) attribute:

```
access_log.propagate = False
```